# RestTemplate/HttpClient changes Spring Boot 1.5 -> 2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Does anyone know of a specific change made in Spring Boot 2.0 or 2.1 that changed the way SSL Host Verification is handled?  Upon upgrading my service I now get `SSLPeerUnverifiedException : Certificate for xyc.com does not match any of the subject alternative names [..]` . Downgrading back to 1.x and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a bug introduced in Apache HttpClient 4.5.9 as noted here [SSLPeerUnverifiedException on matching wildcard certificate](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-dev/201906.mbox/%3CJIRA.13241527.1561479598000.552457.1561649940211@Atlassian.JIRA%3E).  We downgraded to 4.5.8 and the issue went away.  Unsure if they will release a 4.5.10 - or if 5.0 will be the newest version to have fixed this bug.